Is there a fallacy for "A doesn't work very well, therefore B is better than A"?
Assuming that A can be objectively proven to not work very well, and no objective proof is available that B works well.
For example: Allopathic system of medicine has lots of problems, therefore Homeopathy is better than Allopathy.
Is this just a Non-Sequitur? Or is there a more specific fallacy to this?

One way to describe the fallacy is assuming that one A and B belong to some (weighted) set (e.g. all of medicine) which is known to work (up to some degree) on average.  Then, if you find out that A works less than the specified average, given some reasonable assumptions on your prior, your expectations in B would rise.  So the fallacy could be that this greater set (and its assesment) is assumed, when it isn't the case.

All formal fallacies are non sequitur, giving them fancy names doesn't make them more "specific", if it works it should make them more "descriptive".
So the actual problem is that the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises. If that is the case, then you've got yourself a fallacy. Now you could look where the problem is and if you've found that, if you really have to, you can look at a list of fallacies and pick the one most fitting to exemplify that problem in easier terms than the current one.
In this case the problem is that it implies a comparison, but doesn't actually deliver a comparison between the two, so the conclusion is a premature judgement call.
Now with lots of these formal fallacies, just because they are fallacious doesn't mean they are not useful heuristics. The thing is deductive fallacies are already fallacies if there is 1 counter example so that they don't work reliably ALL THE TIME. But if you don't operate in the realm of certainty and perfect precision it might very well be a suitable rule of thumb to go by:
"If A doesn't work very well, let's keep watching for other solutions that could have the potential to do better".
So let's say A has a 0.1% success rate, then there's plenty of room for improvement. If B is worse than A keep A and take the difference between the two as research cost (not much lost). While if B is better than A, keep B and enjoy the better success rate. There obviously is a point or regime where the exploration vs exploitation comparison might turn the other way around, but as long as A barely works at all that risk is fairly low.
The crucial problem here is an inflated degree of certainty. Like B isn't or doesn't have to be better than A. If A works just a little, B could even be worse, it's just that given the room for improvement is still large, there is a good chance doing something else COULD yield an improvement. Not is/does, but just could.
Now in that particular case you also have a lack of information. Like what are you comparing the two by? Do they even have a shared characteristic by which you can compare them? Do you even know enough about B to make a comparison to begin with? Like allopathy and homeopathy are afaik both pseudoscience by the same guy so they likely both don't work beyond the placebo effect, but "better" is a weasel word and among the F tier medicines, homeopathy might still be better in some regard to allopathy for fixing one of it's flaws (whether that was a significant one and made things better in terms of being effective, isn't necessarily required for it to be "better"). So it's hard to say whether that statement is actually false.
Though what you could say is that this degree of certainty is unwarranted and that the conclusion does not follow from the very limited set of information that you were actually given. Homeopathy could still be worse or in the same category of trash as allopathy. From allopathy barely working does not follow that homeopathy does work (better). A does not imply B.
Disclaimer: Though if that is not an exercise in logic but an attempt to disprove a point. You might realize that calling it a fallacy might not do much as that is likely more of a psychological problem where people put an unwarranted amount of confidence in their heuristics because they committed to a mode of operation that either already worked for them or was recommended as working well and it might very well do so most of the time. Just not in that case.
So telling them that it doesn't work all the time, might just trigger a "duh" and nothing else.
In terms of how you could name it. You could call it the Gambler's fallacy:

the incorrect belief that separate, independent events can affect the likelihood of another random event.

Though while fitting, I'm not sure it would be the first though or immediately obvious so you might want to search further for others that are more descriptive, again under the hood they are all non sequitur...

"If I'd asked people what they wanted, they would have said 'better heuristics'." People don't know Latin, so 'fallacy' rolls off the tongue better than 'non sequitur'.

Fallacy is also Latin https://www.etymonline.com/word/fallacy though granted the French and English language had used it for long enough that it appear a whole lot less foreign :) Personally I like the German Trugschluss (deceiving conclusion).

Well, first of all the statement "Allopathic system of medicine has lots of problems" might be true to some extent, but it's a vast oversimplification. Medicine has made tremendous strides in treating many diseases.
The statement "therefore Homeopathy is better than Allopathy" is a non-sequitur. The fact that mainstream medicine has limitations doesn't make a fake medicine called homeopathy not only superior, it doesn't make it medicine at all. It's the same as saying - oh, you spend 10 sec to run 100m, I guess my invisible friend elf can do it better. :)
But if we step aside from the specific example and just look at A and B, there are three fallacies here at least.

False Dichotomy: This fallacy presents only two options, A and B, as if they are the only possibilities. It ignores the possibility of other options, or that both A and B might have their own strengths and weaknesses.

Appeal to Lack of Evidence: This fallacy argues that even there's no proof that B works well, it must be better than A, which is known to have problems. The absence of evidence doesn't automatically prove the opposite. (and in this case is just factually wrong cause homeopathy was proven to be just placebo by many studies)

Fallacy of the Excluded Middle: This fallacy assumes that if A is not perfect, then B must be better. It ignores the possibility that both A and B could be flawed or that neither option is ideal.




Allopathic system of medicine has lots of problems, therefore Homeopathy is better than Allopathy.

The second clause is a complete non sequitur unless there is evidence that Homeopathy (1)does not also have the problems of Allopathy and (2)can accomplish  (most of) whatever Allopathy can do.
Therefore as a standalone statement,  Allopathic system of medicine has lots of problems, therefore Homeopathy is better than Allopathy is meaningless. If ,however,  it is being said in conjunction  with or a summation of some other reasons why Homeopathy is inherently better than Allopathy then it makes total sense.
